# Alfresco Share - Unable to change the default port number

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to configure Alfresco Community 3.3 on a port other than its default port of 8080. I need it to run on 8989. I think I have change all instances of 8080 (where it is mentioned in configuration files) to 8989, and I am able to access Alfresco Explorer okay. So far so good.

But, when I try to access `http://localhost:8989/share` I get the following error

> java.io.IOException: Unable to test document path:
>   alfresco/site-data/configurations/slingshot.site.configuration.xml in
>   remote store: alfresco due to error: 404

The files I have changed are as follows:

- tomcat/conf/server.xml
- tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension/share-config-custom.xml
- tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/file-severs.xml
- tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/repository.properties
- tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/subsystem/sysAdmin/default/sysadmin-parameter.properties
- tomcat/webapps/alfresco/wsdl/access-control-service.wsdl
- tomcat/webapps/alfresco/wsdl/administration-service.wsdl
- tomcat/webapps/alfresco/wsdl/action-service.wsdl
- tomcat/webapps/alfresco/wsdl/authentication-service.wsdl
- tomcat/webapps/alfresco/wsdl/authoring-service.wsdl
- tomcat/webapps/alfresco/wsdl/classification-service.wsdl
- tomcat/webapps/alfresco/wsdl/content-service.wsdl
- tomcat/webapps/alfresco/wsdl/dictionary-service.wsdl
- tomcat/webapps/alfresco/wsdl/repository-service.wsdl
- virtual-tomcat/conf/server-minimal.xml
- virtual-tomcat/conf/server.xml

Have I missed something obvious?

(Please make no suggestions about upgrading......)

Answer (score 6):

I think you have overdone it.

According to 
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Changing_Default_Port_Configuration
you should only change it in share-config-custom.xml

Change all the files back but share-config-custom.xml

Comment: Take a look [here too](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/end-user-discussions/alfresco-share/howto-change-default-port-8080-09132010-2110)

Answer (score 0):

Four are the files to be changed in Alfresco 5.2 in order to set the various ports:

- [alfresco-community_instDir]\properties.ini
- [alfresco-community_instDir]\tomcat\conf\server.xml
- [alfresco-community_instDir]\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco-global.properties
- [alfresco-community_instDir]\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\share-cmis-config.xml